# Set the Horizontal Position of a cursor on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a Swing Application where a user has to Input Some information. I need the cursor By default to be at Position 10 of the JtextField: I have tried these Two Methods but none of them has worked for me:

```
JTextField text = new JTextField("          ", 50);
text.setHorizontalAlignment(10)
```

The other one I have tried is

```
JTextField text = new JTextField("          ", 50);
text.setCaretPosition(10)
```

Is there really a way to do what am trying?

Comment: Thank you :D! We all appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't the problem come from your JTextField containing an empty String ?

If you want the cursor to be at a set position, this position should be reachable, i.e having a String containing 10 blank spaces.

PS : I think `setCaretPosition` is the right method here.

Comment: See the Modified code But the cursor is still at the beginging Postion

Comment: You changed your empty String into the String "23" but this new String still isn't 10 character long. Try with "1234567890" : ten numbers or whatever character you want.

Comment: Isn't there a way of doing that without Putting anything In that String? Something Like (I edited)

Comment: Ah I got it am voting for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
text.getCaret().setDot(10);
```

Comment: text.getCaret().setDot(10); Does not Work. the cursor is still at the Beginging Position of the JtextField. What could be the catch here?